# How to match string inside second set of brackets with Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is my string:

```
type_logistics[][delivery]
type_logistics[][random]
type_logistics[][word]
```

I would like to pull out the word, whatever it is, inside the second set of brackets. I thought that meant doing something like this:

1. Indicate that the start of the string I want to capture is `[` by writing `^\[`
2. Indicate that there will be any number 1+ of characters using `[a-z]+`
3. Indicate that the end will be `]` by using `\]$`
4. The above three steps should get me to `[delivery], [random], [word]` in which case I'd just wrap the entire regex in a capture parenthesis `()`

My finished statement would have been

```
string.match(/^\[([a-z]+)\]$/)
```

Have been playing with regex101.com and literally none of my assumptions have worked LOL. Please help?

Comment: can you explain *why* that is your string? What are you doing that this would be your input? Because that looks like code, not just "a string", which means you can forget about using regex: don't use regular expressions as a parser.

Comment: It's the name for an input attribute following Rail's nested attributes convention `<input name="type_logistics[][delivery]" >`. But I need to parse it because the JS is triggering some class changes based on exactly which nested attribute is changing. I.e., when input with name of nested attribute delivery is clicked, something related to delivery gets a new class

Comment: so your input isn't three lines, it's one line? because that makes a ridiculous difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `^` you are assuming the String you are checking starts there. Your String starts with `type_logistics` and not as expected by the regex with a `[`

To detect the 2nd set of brackets you need to either add the `type_logistics[]` to the regex or just match everything before the 1st set of brackets with `.*`

When working with multiple lines (for example during testing on regex101), don't forget to set the modifiers `gm`

> **g modifier**: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
>  **m modifier**: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each
>   line (not only begin/end of string)

These all would work for your test cases

```
/^.*\[\]\[([a-z]+)\]$/gm

/^type_logistics\[\]\[([a-z]+)\]$/gm

/^.*\[([a-z]+)\]$/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

Match `[` followed by `a-z` followed by `]` , convert back to string, split `[` character, filter `""` empty string

```js
var str = "type_logistics[][delivery] type_logistics[][random] type_logistics[][word]"
var res = str.match(/(\[[a-z]+)(?=\])/g).join("").split(/\[/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(res);
document.body.textContent = res;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could it be done without the `.split(/\[/)`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Probably. Using approach at Answer of capturing `[` at `.match()`, could alternative substitute `.replace()` for `.split()` and `.filter()` possibly `.join()` to remove `[` character and empty string returned by `.split()`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `str.match(/(\[[a-z]+)(?=\])/g).join(" ").replace(/\[/g, "")`

Comment: Ya, nice one, thought about getting rid of that second replace. Passing into a single `replace` fn callback might help (and collecting the results into an array.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Alternatively `String(str.match(/(\[[a-z]+)(?=\])/g)).match(/[a-z]+/g)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `str.replace(/(\[[a-z]+)(?=\])|([^\1])/g, function(match, p1) {
  return match === p1 ? match.slice(1) + " " : ""
})`